# zooming into stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have plotted a stacked bar chart using Google charts API as shown below. As you might notice, the values at the top of the bars are highly unreadable. Is there a way that I can zoom in to see the smaller values clearly?

I see the option `explorer` for area chart but thats not in this kind of chart.

How do I make this chart more readable?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/rO3T0-9aH6M . It's not really what you asked

Comment: It didnt really help :(

Comment: You can set up a function to change the `vAxis.viewWindow.min` and `vAxis.viewWindow.max` options and redraw the chart.  That would create a vertical zoom effect.  If your x-axis is a "date" type, you can do something similar, or use a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) to pan and zoom the x-axis.